# Android ask password on disabling app from device admin?

Tags: android, device-admin

is there any way to ask password on deactivating a device admin from android device
or else to hide or to protect app from un-checking in device administrator.

Comment: Trying to understand what you mean. The preposition mix doesn't make it easy. "from device admin" vs "in device admin" (is "device admin" a person, a role, or software); "disable an app" (what does that mean; apps can be disabled temporarily but also deleted), "deactivate a device admin", what does that mean and how does it relate to the other words you use? @Gopi You seem to have understood it, can you explain?

Comment: thanks for your head up mr.Stacker, just trying to protect an app from de-activation from device admin.

Comment: i have an device admin app and i want to protect my app from un-installing for that i need an password protect on device admin it is an security app for locating a mobile.

Comment: @Gopic.s Core Android philosophy: The user is in charge. No automatic installs, no hiding activities from the outside, no automatic code execution during installation etc -- I may be wrong but I'd be more than surprised if an app would have a chance to defend itself against an admin's act.

Comment: i actually want an protection for my app from uninstalling is there anyway for that any suggestions are appreciated?

Comment: Hi @Gopic.s its the same i need too can you help me?

Comment: i dont have any idea @KrishnaAppu even i am searching for the same!

Comment: @Gopic.s and Krishna, as I already wrote: If you want to do that, you're basically not making an Android app, because it does not go along well with Android philosophy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible. It would actually be a problem if applications could protect themselves from being uninstalled. Just think about a malware application that gets installed and than you can't get rid of it.

Comment: hi @azertiti i can understand, for that purpose i ask for password protection if you want to deselect you must enter password that user who know's the password can un-check the app from device admin and he can uninstall the application isn't it..

Comment: yes @azertiti i needed the same, a user should not uninstall the app without password.

Comment: The device admin page from settings is not under the control of user applications. You can request the access and even unregister your application as an administrator but the password feature is not provided by the system.

Comment: okay thank you @azertiti i there any other way to protect my app from uninstalling.

Comment: AppLock, Android parent control, both apps have implemented same functionality which we want to implement. Any idea?

Comment: @azertiti I dont think that you are right since  as Ahmad Raza is saying truth

Comment: @azertiti This is possible now. Check my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43044075/3565061 Please update your answer to reflect on this.